# Shouldn't random.gauss return values in between mean and the standard deviation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I tried using the `random.gauss` function in Python to get a random value between a range. The gauss function takes mean, standard deviation as parameters. Shouldn't the return value be between `[mean +- standard deviation]`?

Below is the code snippet:

```
for y in [random.gauss(4,1) for _ in range(50)]:
    if y > 5 or y < 3: # shouldn't y be between  (3, 5) ?
        print(y)
```

Output of the code:

```
6.011096878888296
2.9192195126660403
5.020299287583643
2.9322959456674083
1.6704559841869528
```

Comment: Answer is simple: No. Google it if you need...

Comment: Not necessarily.  On average, the value will be 4, the mean, but the values can range up to 3 standard deviations (between 1 and 7 in your case) about 99% of the time, and more the remaining 1%.  Percentages are rough, but give you an idea.  (68% will be between 3 and 5; 95% between 2 and 6, roughly.)

Comment: @millimoose to be fair, it's more about what is a Gaussian distribution, than what is random...

Comment: @Julien - yes and no; the observed mean and deviation of a sample taken from a population with a given distribution are themselves random variables. (Hope I'm using the terminology coherently I took stats nearly a decade ago in German.)

Comment: @millimoose The question is not about estimating the parameters, it's about what to expect when generating from a distribution with the parameters as given.

Comment: @pjs if that is so then this arguably belongs on math.SE or an introductory statistics textbook; from a programming standpoint gauss() works as it’s supposed to and uniform() does what OP seems to want to accomplish

Comment: (I’m amused that for all the comments saying what this question is really about nobody actually answered what a Gaussian distribution is yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shouldn't the return value be between [mean +- standard deviation]?"

No. [For the Gaussian distribution slightly less than 32% of the outcomes will be more than one standard deviation away from the mean in either direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_deviation_and_coverage).  There is no fixed range that contains 100% of the outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian distribution only concern about the probability of a value to deviate from the mean by a certain amount. So, any value is possible, it just that the probability is very low for some range of values

Answer (score -1):

A sample size of 50 is not enough for the sample mean and sample SD to be good estimators of the population mean/SD. [Law of large numbers to the rescue](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_large_numbers):

```
from random import gauss

xs = []

for i in range(100000):
    xs.append(gauss(0,1))

print("mean = ", sum(xs)/len(xs)) # should print a number close to 0
in_sd = len(list(x for x in xs if x > -1 and x < 1))
print("in SD = ",  in_sd/len(xs)) # should print a number close to 0.68
```

(https://repl.it/@millimoose/SiennaFlatBackground)

---

To get random numbers between 3 and 5, use [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform)`(3,  5)` instead.